# Map<bitset,object>-like data structure that can check subsets of bitsets?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, subset, binary-decision-diagram

I have a big huge  hashtable (so big I can't check every row) (in C++ using boost::unordered_map) where the keys are std::bitset and the values are some structure that I have.

Say I have this in the table:

```
00010101 -> {"Hello"}
00100100 -> {"Good Bye"}
01111101 -> {"Whatever"}
```

If I query the map as `map[01111101]` I want it to return "Whatever". That is fine, its what a map is for. 
BUT, if I query `map[00110101]` I want it to return "Hello", BECAUSE "00010101" (the key for Hello) is a subset of "00110101" of my query. I represent sets with bits, I think that's self-explanatory.

If there ever is more than one entry in the table such that the key is a subset of the query, I want them all.

I have no idea if there is anything like this. I am looking at Binary Decision Diagrams, but I have never used them and I am not sure if they would do the trick.

Thanks.

---

Edit: Set representations.
Say I have a group of objects A,B,C,D,E,F,G
I have two sets A,B,C and D,F. I would represent them as 1110000 and 0001010 respectively. Therefore: 1110000 is not a subset of 0001010 (or viceversa), but 1000100 is a subset of 1010101.

Comment: can you explain more specific about what are you referring as a subset? is `00000001` subset of `00110101`?

Comment: I edited the question to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A map based on a hash table is the wrong data structure here.

You can gain some efficiency in discovering all matches by [storing the bit strings in a trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), where trie nodes contain corresponding strings.

Unlike the tries in the link's examples, each node in your case will have 0, 1, or 2 children labeled 0 and/or 1.

Now a lookup in your case moves traverses the trie in a customized manner. For each 1 in the search key, you will search both the corresponding 0 and 1 link of the trie. For each 0, search only the 0 branch.  The nodes that you find will be just the ones you want.

Search time will be proportional to the total bit string length of key values searched, which in the worst case is all elements in the tree.

**Adding code**

Here is a toy C implementation for reference.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

// Simple bit vectors of arbitrary length.
typedef struct {
  unsigned n_bits;
  unsigned *bits;
} BIT_VECTOR;

void init_bit_vector(BIT_VECTOR *v) {
  v->n_bits = 0;
  v->bits = NULL;
}

void setup_bit_vector(BIT_VECTOR *v, unsigned n_bits) {
  v->n_bits = n_bits;
  v->bits = calloc((n_bits + WORD_BIT - 1) / WORD_BIT, sizeof(unsigned));
}

void clear_bit_vector(BIT_VECTOR *v) {
  free(v->bits);
  v->n_bits = 0;
}

void set_bit_vector(BIT_VECTOR *v, unsigned *bits, unsigned n_bits) {
  unsigned n_words = (n_bits + WORD_BIT - 1) / WORD_BIT;
  for (int i = 0; i < n_words; i++) v->bits[i] = bits[i];
  v->n_bits = n_bits;
}

unsigned get_bit(BIT_VECTOR *v, int i) {
  unsigned mask = 1u << (i % WORD_BIT);
  return !!(v->bits[i / WORD_BIT] & mask);
}

// A trie map from bit vectors to strings.
typedef struct trie_s {
  struct trie_s *b[2];
  char *val;
} TRIE;

TRIE *make_trie(void) {
  TRIE *trie = malloc(sizeof *trie);
  trie->b[0] = trie->b[1] = NULL;
  trie->val = NULL;
  return trie;
}

// Add a key/value entry to the given trie map.
void put(TRIE *trie, BIT_VECTOR *key, char *val) {
  TRIE *p = trie;
  for (int i = 0; i < key->n_bits; ++i) {
    unsigned bit = get_bit(key, i);
    if (!p->b[bit]) p->b[bit] = make_trie();
    p = p->b[bit];
  }
  p->val = val;
}

// Recursive search that implements the subset membership check.
static void search(TRIE *trie, BIT_VECTOR *key, int i, char **buf, unsigned *n) {
  if (!trie) return;
  if (i == key->n_bits) {
    if (trie->val) buf[(*n)++] = trie->val;
    return;
  }
  unsigned bit = get_bit(key, i);
  // A standard trie search does this.
  search(trie->b[bit], key, i + 1, buf, n);
  // But here, add a search of the 0 branch if the key bit is 1.
  if (bit) search(trie->b[0], key, i + 1, buf, n);
}

// Get all entries with keys a subset of the search key.
unsigned get_all(TRIE *trie, BIT_VECTOR *key, char **buf) {
  int n = 0;
  search(trie, key, 0, buf, &n);
  return n;
}

typedef struct {
  unsigned bits;
  char *val;
} EXAMPLE_DATA;

int main(void) {
  TRIE *trie = make_trie();
  #define N (sizeof data / sizeof data[0])
  EXAMPLE_DATA data[] = {
    { 0b00010101, "Hello" },
    { 0b00100100, "Goodbye" },
    { 0b00101101, "Farewell" },
    { 0b01111101, "Whatever"},
  };
  BIT_VECTOR key[1];
  init_bit_vector(key);
  setup_bit_vector(key, 8);
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    set_bit_vector(key, &data[i].bits, 8);
    put(trie, key, data[i].val);
  }
  unsigned search_val = 0b00110101;
  set_bit_vector(key, &search_val, 8);
  char *buf[N];
  unsigned n = get_all(trie, key, buf);
  printf("Found:\n");
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    printf(" %s", buf[i]);
  printf(".\n");
  clear_bit_vector(key);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but isn't it the other way around (explore both branches for 0 and 1 for 1?). In the example table, I get a trie like this: (0,[ (0, [ 010101| 100100] )| 1111101]) (-> this means root 0, with two sub-tries, the left with root 0, the right is just the string 1111101. The left has two children, one is the string 010101 and the right 100100)

So if my key is 00110101, I expect to get the two sub-tries on the left. Thus recursing on both 0 and 1 when I see a "0" in the key. Effectivelly, int his example, I would have to go through all the trie, right?

Comment: @excalibur1491  Not as I read your example of "subset". I'm assuming that a 1 in the search key should produce results that have either a corresponding 0 or 1 in the stored key.  So you'd have to search both sides of the trie at the corresponding node.

Comment: You are absolutely right, this indeed seems to match what I was looking for! thanks!

Comment: I think search time can be much larger than "the total bit string length of the key values found". Consider the set of w+1-bit strings consisting of all w-bit strings prepended to a 0, and then consider what happen when searching for a string with w 0s and then a 1. All 2^w strings are candidates until the leaf nodes are inspected, and then none are. "the total bit string length of the key values found" is 0, but the search time is &Omega;(2^w).

Answer (score -1):

Ok, let's simplified things with `map < int, string >`. Now i have this

```
map < int,string > myMap;
myMap[13] = "Hello"; //13 is 00010101
myMap[36] = "Good Bye";
```

Given a `key`, you want all subset to be printed. All you have to do is go through all the key and check if the `key` is a subset of the `map key`. You can achieve this with `&` binary opperation (which i know can work on bitset (yeah they are binary operation after all)). Let's take a look after this simple explanation.

> say 13 in binary is 00010101
>
> Now you have 00000001 which is subset of 00010101.

To be called subset, one must contain only TRUE bit from the actual set. On other terms, if it's TRUE bit on subset, then it must be TRUE bit on actual set. (If the third bit is 1 on subset, so it's must be 1 on the actual set)

You can check it using `&`, because after you operate `&` and get the exact same value as the key, you know that the key is subset from the actual set.

> 1 & 13 is 1 //00001 is subset of 10101
>
> 4 & 13 is 4 //00100 is subset of 10101

And how about something not or a half subset from actual set?

> 2 & 13 is 0 //00010 is not subset of 10101
>
> 3 & 13 is 1 //00011 is not subset of 10101 because the second bit is not TRUE

See? the result from `&` is must be the same as the key. Now time for program

```
int main(){
    map < int , string > myMap;
    myMap[13] = "Hello"; //00010101
    myMap[36] = "Good Bye"; //00100100
    int key;
    cin >> key;
    for(auto it = myMap.cbegin(); it != myMap.cend(); ++it){
        if((key & (*it).first) == key){ //Check if subset
            cout << (*it).second << endl; //print if subset
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

There you go, hope it helps.

Reading source [cbegin](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/cbegin/), [bitset operator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/operators/)

Comment: I suspect OP is hoping for something more efficient than looking at every entry in the table, since the table is apparently "big huge".

Comment: As rici says, my table is way to big to loop, and I need this to run as fast as possible. Thanks for the suggestion though :)

Comment: If endeed your table is way to big, so why don't you just use distributed system?

Comment: Distributed as in "parallel"? Not sure what you mean :)

Comment: Yeah, if your data is way to big. You can use said MapReduce idea. Simple yet can run on multiple pc resulting in faster processing :)